# MySQL float values all become NULL when default NULL is used

Tags: mysql, database

I create the following table and set default value of FLOAT as NULL because I want missing float value to be stored as NULL in the table. But the problem is after I set default as NULL in the table, all customerReviewAverage values become NULL. 
The following are the code with which I created the table and loaded data.

```
CREATE TABLE Products(sku INTEGER, name VARCHAR(255), description TEXT,
                          regularPrice FLOAT,
                          customerReviewAverage FLOAT default NULL );
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'product.csv'
    INTO TABLE Products
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (sku, name, @description, regularPrice, @customerReviewAverage)
    SET description = IF(@description='',NULL,@description);
```

This is a sample of data in product.csv.

```
19658847,Glanzlichter - CD,,12.99,5.0
19658856,Glanzlichter - CD,,6.99,
19658865,Glanzlichter - CD,,8.99,
1965886,Beach Boys '69 - CASSETTE,,6.99,4.5
```

Later I found that

```
(sku, name, @description, regularPrice, @customerReviewAverage)
```

should be modified as

```
(sku, name, @description, regularPrice, customerReviewAverage)
```

Comment: where are you setting `@customerReviewAverage` ?

Comment: It is a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Questions like this remind me of why I load data into staging tables where all the columns are strings and then do the type conversions in SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yeah, good solution. I also got into that a few years back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(sku, name, @description, regularPrice, @customerReviewAverage)
SET 
description = IF(@description='',NULL,@description),
customerReviewAverage = IF(@customerReviewAverage='',NULL,@customerReviewAverage);
```

Your "missing" values are an empty text in the CSV.

Since your `mysql` version isn't running this ok, you can do a separate update:

```
UPDATE Products SET customerReviewAverage = NULL WHERE customerReviewAverage = 0
```

Comment: Doesn't help how? what are they inserted like with this code?

Comment: Missing values becom zeros.

Comment: I just ran it and it inserted: `5, NULL, NULL, 4.5` for `customerReviewAverage`

Comment: What's your version of MySQL?

Comment: 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1

Comment: I just tried again with this version of MySQL, but the result is the same

Comment: That's not what I want because NULL is different from 0.

Comment: Do you remove the tailing comma in the tuples?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105511/discussion-between-alex-tartan-and-zhu-li).