# How to store missing FLOAT values with NULL in SQL

Tags: mysql, database

In the other question, I asked about why non-empty values become NULL. But in this question, I asked about how I could make empty values become NULL but not zero.

I found that missing float values are always represented as  0, but not NULL. How could I change that?

The following are the codes with which I created the table and loaded data.

```
CREATE TABLE Products(sku INTEGER, name VARCHAR(255), description TEXT,
                          regularPrice FLOAT,
                          customerReviewAverage FLOAT default NULL );
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'product.csv'
    INTO TABLE Products
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (sku, name, @description, regularPrice, customerReviewAverage)
    SET description = IF(@description='',NULL,@description);
```

This is a sample of data in product.csv.

```
19658847,Glanzlichter - CD,,12.99,5.0
19658856,Glanzlichter - CD,,6.99,
19658865,Glanzlichter - CD,,8.99,
1965886,Beach Boys '69 - CASSETTE,,6.99,4.5
```

Comment: So basically you want to do the same for the `regularPrice` value, as you are doing for `description` already? Then what’s stopping you?

Comment: It takes no effect for reviewAverage

Comment: Exact duplicate of [MySQL float values all become NULL when default NULL is used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832344/mysql-float-values-all-become-null-when-default-null-is-used)

Comment: @EJP It is true that this is a part of that problem. But obviously they are not the same at all.  I ask this question again so that the exact problem in this question is not veiled by the title of that question.

Comment: @EJP If you really mind it, I could just remove the corresponding part in that question, although some people may find the only answer under that question very weird.

Comment: They are exactly the same. NULL values are stored as NULL in any SQL database. The problem in how you are supplying the data.

Comment: @EJP that question is about a mistake in MySQL syntax. This question is about how to store empty float value in SQL as NULL which is in fact stored as 0.

Comment: @EJP I have deleted the corresponding part from another question. Now the two questions are very different, although they have the similar data and code. Please read two questions closely if you don't want to revoke duplicate.

Comment: @EJP Just one more remind: In the other question, "float values all become NULL" means that non-empty and non-zero values all become NULL.  And in this question, I just want empty values to be NULL, not zero, and not-empty and non-zero values are stored correctly here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is how MySQL interprets an *empty field* vs a *missing field*.  [From the docs for LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)...

> If an input line has too few fields, the table columns for which input fields are missing are set to their default values.
>
> An empty field value is interpreted different from a missing field.  For string types, the column is set to the empty string. For numeric types, the column is set to 0.

In this case it seems MySQL considers it to be *empty*.  You can see this from `show warnings`.

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                    |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'customerReviewAverage' at row 2 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'customerReviewAverage' at row 3 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Whereas if we remove the trailing commas so the field is *missing*...

```
19658847,Glanzlichter - CD,,12.99,5.0
19658856,Glanzlichter - CD,,6.99
19658865,Glanzlichter - CD,,8.99
1965886,Beach Boys '69 - CASSETTE,,6.99,4.5
```

Then the data is set to null.

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                    |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1261 | Row 2 doesn't contain data for all columns |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+

mysql> select * from products;   
+----------+---------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| sku      | name                      | description | regularPrice | customerReviewAverage |
+----------+---------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| 19658847 | Glanzlichter - CD         | NULL        |        12.99 |                     5 |
| 19658856 | Glanzlichter - CD         | NULL        |         6.99 |                  NULL |
| 19658865 | Glanzlichter - CD         | NULL        |         8.99 |                  NULL |
|  1965886 | Beach Boys '69 - CASSETTE | NULL        |         6.99 |                   4.5 |
+----------+---------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Doing the same thing for `@customerReviewAverage` as for `@description` worked for me in MySQL 5.7.

```
LOAD DATA
  LOCAL INFILE 'product.csv'
  INTO TABLE Products
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  (sku, name, @description, regularPrice, @customerReviewAverage)       
  SET description           = IF(@description='',NULL,@description),
      customerReviewAverage = IF(@customerReviewAverage='',NULL,@customerReviewAverage);

mysql> select * from products;
+----------+---------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| sku      | name                      | description | regularPrice | customerReviewAverage |
+----------+---------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| 19658847 | Glanzlichter - CD         | NULL        |        12.99 |                     5 |
| 19658856 | Glanzlichter - CD         | NULL        |         6.99 |                  NULL |
| 19658865 | Glanzlichter - CD         | NULL        |         8.99 |                  NULL |
|  1965886 | Beach Boys '69 - CASSETTE | NULL        |         6.99 |                   4.5 |
+----------+---------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I see. Now I understand the difference. So there is no solution when the trailing comma is not removed?

Comment: @ZhuLi There is, it's at the end of the answer. Do the same thing as you did with `description`.  `customerReviewAverage = IF(@customerReviewAverage='',NULL,@customerReviewAverage)`.

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't work in 5.5.47-0+deb8u1 (Debian).

Comment: I tested it again and found that when I load small set of data, it could work. But when I load large set of data, it doesn't work.